# Can we use SendGrid Template with ActionMailer in Ruby on Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-ruby, sendgrid-rails

I want to use SendGrid Template which I developed on SendGrid with ActionMailer instead of using app/views/test_mailer/test.html.erb in one of our Ruby on Rails Application. How can I do it?
Any suggestions

Comment: https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-ruby-library/blob/master/docs/TransactionalEmailsApi.md#get_smtp_template and https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-ruby-library/blob/master/docs/TransactionalEmailsApi.md#send_template

Comment: I haven't used these methods but they look promising